# PyQt4.QtWebKit: QWebPage QWebView set timeout when load stop

Tags: webkit, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qwebview, qwebpage

Is there any way to say to a QWebPage or to a QWebView stop loading page if some sort of timeout is exceeded?

Sultan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) uses QTWebKit and it has a max-wait parameter. You should take a look at how they do it. It should have something to do with QTimer.

Answer (score 6):

I have had exactly the same problem with my page scraping app that would sometimes take too long on certain JavaScript calls.

In my app I add a single shot timer that on expiry calls a method "as if" the page has finished loading like this:

```
self.timer = QTimer()
self.timer.singleShot(15000, self.finished_loading)
```

You can see the whole source on [my GitHub](https://github.com/radekstepan/skyScraper/blob/master/webkit.py).